# How to run custom Javascript code in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, webapi

May be this question is not new, but stuck here.

I have designed a beautiful looking website using WordPress.
My Question is I Want to run some custom javascript code that I have written to manipulate elements of worpress page.

Second I have created an API,
I Have Designed a Questionire Page. Whenever someone click on the sumit button I Want Wordpress to send all the filled details in post request to my Web API that accept POST request. Then wait for the response and Create the Wordpress page as per the response using JavaScript.

Comment: There are plugins that enable you to add arbitrary javascript to page. Although I would handle the API call and the redirection from the server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'wp_head','custom_js_code' );
function custom_js_code(){
 echo '<script>PUT YOUR JAVASCRIPT CODES HERE...</script>';
}
```